# Request mandatory for POST method call in Karate

Tags: karate

Today I came across a scenario where there was a POST method call but that does not require a request data and query parameters are sufficient. But in Karate framework it is mandatory to give request data when it is POST method. So I had to provide request as 'null' explicitly. Is there any way in Karate that if there is no request data then you can skip providing request data as 'null'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I usually do if there's no request body :

Given path '/path/to//action'
    And request ''
    When method post
    Then status 200

(Haven't found a way to skip the request step)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way:

```
Given url 'url'
And params param_value
And request '{}'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Its same as mentioned above just I gave empty request body